# How to configure dinamically a processor in Apache NiFi by a flow file?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a use case like in the following pseudo code (attached image):

1. Generate a flow file (#1) with n attributes;
2. Process the flow file (#1) through an initial route, A; nodes: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,   3, 4, 5,   9;
3. Generate new flow files (#2, #3, #x) with n attributes;
4. Process the new flow files (#2, #3, #x) through an alternate route, B; nodes: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,   9;

Other info:

- Node 4: UpdateAttribute, contains `number` attribute (property) which is set to 0.
- Node 4: contains an advanced rule (attached image):
  Conditions:
  Expression:
  `${execution.status:le(0)}`;
  `${number:le(0)}`;
  Actions:
  Attribute:
  `number`;
  Value:
  `${number:plus(1)}`;
- Node 5: RouteOnAttribute, routes based on `number` value, 0 / 1;
- Node 7: add 0 in 'execution.status' attribute (flow file #1);

I'm able to route the flow file #1 as in step 4, but after that all new flow files (#2, #3, #x) are not routed like as I expected in step 4.

My question is, how can I configure dinamically a processor in Apache NiFi by a flow file?

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked out the NiFi expression language? Will that solve your issue? https://www.nifi.rocks/expression-language-cheat-sheet/

Comment: That's nice, but I'm not really sure that in the current use case NEL is going to help. However I'm thinking to change the approach and use NiFi API. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. Wanted to at least ask!